# How to extend WIFI from ethernet

Tags: networking

Here's my current setup.

Bonded "Zone" DSL modem/router on main level serving laptop #1 via Ethernet and laptop #2 via WIFI.  WIFI does not serve basement level well, so I have Ethernet running to basement where it is divided by a switch with one Ethernet going to laptop #3 and another Ethernet going to entertainment system, which houses a Sony Playstation 3. The PS3 has gone on the fritz and is now only good for playing discs, so I recently added a Google Chromecast to the TV. The Chromecast, of course is WIFI only, and is only receiving a weak signal. Plus I need to have a decent WIFI signal to my phone, which is the interface device for the Chromecast. So what I would like to do is to use the Ethernet that was serving the PS3 and broadcast WIFI from it. What device can I plug the Ethernet into that will do this for me? And if you have a recommendation, are there any special setup instructions?

Answer (score 2):

You just need a wireless router that supports AP mode, lets you turn off its DHCP server, *or* can be set to a seperate DHCP range. There's also standalone access points - which might be the cheapest option.

In my case I have a primary router (connected to a ONT for fibre optic internet) connected to a Asus router that has AP mode support.

In the past I've used

1. A WRT54GL with DHCP turned off but no 'AP mode' to speak of with three consumer routers - one acting *as* a router (dlink of some sort), one in AP mode (asus), and one with DHCP turned off(WRT54GL/DDWRT), one network setup. The WRT failed, and you can see a detailed description of the setup [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/806656/finding-the-ip-address-of-a-walled-in-router).

[image]

2. A wierd 2wire ADSL modem router that *wouldn't* let me turn off DHCP, I used a different IP address range, and the horrible hack that is double nat. That *did* isolate the two networks. The set up even extends to *triple* nat - I tested a 192.168.1.x subnet connected to a 10.0.0.x subnet inside a 192.168.1.x subnet for... complete horror.

Things to look out for.

In general with AP mode or DHCP turned off you need to connect two 'regular' ethernet connectors on either AP. Don't use the 'internet' ethernet connector there (I have an answer explaining this somewhere, but I can't find it).

Make sure your 'AP' has a *fixed* known IP address, preferably outside your DHCP range, so that you can find it if something breaks.

Have different SSIDs so you *know* you're on the right AP.

Comment: Thanks Journeyman... This just gave new life to my buried-in-the-closet, decade-old WRT54G.  Wireless and ethernet are both working with this setup.

Answer (score 1):

A Wireless Access Point or a router configured as such.

Answer (score 0):

All OSes support sharing an Ethernet connection between wifi clients, so if you feel like doing a little bit of work, you can get away with a totally free solution. What you need to do is to transform the wifi set up of one of your pcs in a "hotspot".

The solution does depend of course upon your OS.

1. If you are running Windows, a Google search for these keywords "Windows transform pc hotspot" unveils lots of Web pages giving you instructions, including a good Youtube video, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhA5cnNSqK0); you only have the embarrasment of choice.
2. If you are running Linux, I suggest you Google-search "Name_of_your_distro hostapd". hostapd is the program which enables the hotspot on your pc.
3. If you run Mac OS, you have once more the embarrassment of choice. I like [this particular guide](http://www.macyourself.com/2009/02/23/turn-your-mac-into-a-wifi-hotspot-using-os-xs-internet-sharing/), but I suggest you make up your own mind among the billions Web pages offering advice on how to do this; once again a Google search for "Mac OS transform pc hotspot" will uncover all the advice you may need.

For once, it is nice to be able to say: it is all free.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I have one other question that came to mind after my original post.  Considering that the location of my entertainment system does get a weak signal from the wifi coming from the modem/router upstairs, if I then also enable wifi downstairs using ethernet on the same network, is there any chance for conflict in receiving wifi from two different signals on the same network, or will the device(s) (i.e. the Chromecast and my phone) just pick up on the strongest signal?

Comment: @James Watt None whatsoever, and the reason is not that you are receiving a weak signal, because there is a solution that would allow you to set up a second wifi network even if the signal were very strong. You can always choose a different frequency channel, irrespective of the device (AP, pc, ...) you decide to use to provide wifi coverage to your basement. Just make sure you pick two well-separated channels, something like 1 and 6 for instance, not 8 and 9. That's all.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I tried configuring it manually by creating an Ad Hoc network, but for whatever reason the network I created never showed up, even though the network sharing center said it was created successfully and ready to use.  However I was able to make it work for the most part using the virtual router program.  There were some windows compatibility issues but they got sorted out.

Comment: Now the distance from my laptop to the entertainment system is not really any better, and my phone wants to keep kicking me off of the virtual network and back to the main wifi from upstairs, which puts my phone and the Chromecast on separate networks, which of course won't serve me.  I'm going to look into a WAP to connect to the ethernet that feeds directly to my entertainment system.  Any recommendations on and affordable and effective one?

Comment: @James Watt 3 comments. 1) I did not suggest an Ad Hoc network, that cannot work. If you tell me your OS, I will be more precise as to the name of the solution. 2) How come you have 2 networks? You should have only one DHCP server, thus only 1 network. 3) Product recommendations are forbidden on this site, but try not to go for really cheap products, it may sound trite but there is a reason why they are cheap.

Comment: OK, thanks again for your response. The reason I tried the Ad Hoc network is that it was one of the first and most frequent results when I did a google search. I'm on Windows7. When I successfully created the wireless connection with the virtual router, what it had me do was to name the connection, choose a security option and give it a password.  So, though it may all be part of the same network I then had more than one choice for access points.  Essentially the Chromecast sees it as being on a different network than my phone unless I'm connected through the same point. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does. Glad I could help a little