# What type of ethernet-to-wireless extender do I need

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

My house is wired for ethernet.  So far, I've got everything taken care of with gigabit switches in most rooms to handle XBoxes, PCs, etc.  Until today.  My Amazon Firestick arrived and only connects with WiFi.

I have a [Rec10](http://www.ampedwireless.com/products/rec10.html) from AmpedWireless, but it's just a wireless repeater and the signal isn't strong enough to reach the back of the house.

What kind of gadget do I need (and/or what's the right term to search for) for something that will plug into the ethernet in the back room and re-broadcast Wifi?  The searches on SU and others often refer to keeping the same SSID as my router... I don't care about that.  I just want it to work with minimal fuss.  This [post](https://superuser.com/questions/668655/how-to-extend-wifi-from-ethernet) from last year was the closest one I could find, but didn't really have an answer.

Brands, technology, jargon, and experience are appreciated.

Thanks.