# Easiest way to get wifi if signal is too weak

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, switch

I want to get wi-fi internet access on a smartphone in a certain place. I have a switch there, it is connected by a 20 meters long network cable to a wi-fi router, the router is connected to the internet. The signal of the router is not strong enough to cover the area where I want to receive the wi-fi signal.

What is the easiest way to get wi-fi connection at that place, where I only have a network cable and a switch?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/668655/how-to-extend-wifi-from-ethernet

Comment: use a [802.11 range extender](https://www.bing.com/search?q=802.11+extender&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR)

Comment: To extend the signal I would need a power socket somewhere. But the cable goes form a house to a restaurant. I was thinking about using the network cable that I have there. I tried to plug a wifi router into it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For placed that are covered badly by my wifi router I use a repeater plugged to the wall which extends the routers signal. [There are drawbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater) but depending on the repeater they are fairly cheap and easy to setup.

Other choice would be to connect a second wifi router to the cable where currently your switch is connected.

Quickest solution you could test is place tinfoil on your wifi routers antenna(s) to work as a dish.

Comment: The solution with the wifi router would be preferred, but I tried it and it didn't work. I suppose the router must be configured properly for this setup?

Comment: What exactly didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a wired connection already, setting up another wireless network is trivial: Get a router or access point, turn off its DHCP server (if any) and make sure its IP address doesn’t collide with the existing router. Then, set up the wireless network to your liking. You might want to use the “original” network’s configuration to enable roaming (of sorts).

After configuring the router, set it up at the desired location and connect one of its LAN (*not* WAN!) ports to the existing wired network.